# Use Datetime.UTC to set West Central Africa time

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to save the `Datetime` of where my client Software works.

The client is based in West Central Africa. I used `Datetime.Now` during `development` and was working fine but in `production`, the time displayed is `-1 hour late`. How do I make use of `Datetime.Utc` to show the exact time.

Note that West Central Africa is `utc+1`.

I have tried the below but it only shows UTC+1

```
TimeZoneInfo NaijaZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Central Africa Standard Time");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your application is used internationally, I recommend you use

`DateTimeOffset` rather than `DateTime`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=netcore-3.1

To compare between DateTime and DateTimeOffset
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime

**the usage** is exactly the same of DataTime, the only difference is that DateTimeOffset adds the time offset that you can use when display to End-User Interface

Comment: Thank you for the response. Exactly what I was looking for...

Comment: @uthumvc happy for that, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

**If** you *only* want to show W Africa time (regardless of client), then you can do something like this:

```
var utc = DateTime.UtcNow;

//this is your stated offset from UTC
//Caveat: Daylight Savings, if/when applicable
var offset = 1;

Console.WriteLine(utc - new TimeSpan(offset *-1, 0, 0));
```

There will undoubtedly comments about using `FindSystemTimeZoneById` or similar to get `W. Central Africa Standard Time` (just as you have above) *instead of setting the offset specifically*, and if it works, then that would be the recommended way:

```
// Note: DateTime.UtcNow
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, "W. Central Africa Standard Time");
```

However, depending on what you mean by "production" (systems you deploy to, not in your control, what version of .Net, core, container, etc.) [you may/may not have them, have different ids, etc.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FpblGM):

```
    //Note: UTC
    var utc = DateTime.UtcNow;
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(utc, "W. Central Africa Standard Time"));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        var offset = 1;
        Console.WriteLine(utc - new TimeSpan(offset * -1, 0, 0));
        //List what's available on "this" system...
        var sysZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
        if (sysZones.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo in sysZones)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{timeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset} : {timeZoneInfo.Id}");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No zones here...");
        }
    }
```

Hth...

Comment: Thank you for this response and the insight as well